# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping

Im new to spring mvc, earlier I accessed homepage via root package name "localhost/spring", and I cant find out what i'd  changed that i got this error.
Web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Homepage Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Inject
public HomeController(UserServiceImpl userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}   

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String home(Model model) {

    System.out.println("Sdfsd");

    model.addAttribute("users", userService.getUsers());

    return "home";
}

}
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
    <annotation-driven />


<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="by.mvc.dao" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/user_db" /> 
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="by.mvc.dao" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties"> 
        <beans:props> 
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop> 
        </beans:props> 
    </beans:property> 
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What is the url you are using?

Comment: localhost/spring - name of base package, or localhost/SpringMvc - project name - the same result

Comment: One more question, what package contains homecontroller?

Comment: package by.mvc.spring

Comment: changing web.xml and requestmapping had no effect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the application may not be scanning the package that contains the controllers.  I see a dao package being scanned but I assume you wouldn't put your controllers there.  In your configuration scan the package with the controllers.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.mvc.spring" />
```

Comment: then i get this error:
No matching bean of type [by.mvc.dao.UserServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Good so the controller is working.  Add `@Component` to the UserServiceImpl class and make sure its in one of the packages being scanned.  Then add `@Autowired` to the userService field in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tags like `@RequestMapping`, `@Controller`, etc, you have to use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` instead of `<annotation-driven />`.

[Here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) you have more information about it.

Comment: No, since in his servlet-context mvc is defined as standard namespace!

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Just use **<mvc:annotation-driven />** in **root-context.xml** instead using **<annotation-driven />** in **servlet-context.xml**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `<annotation-driven />` and you have one o more packages using @RequestMapping, @Controller you have to set the tag `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc.example" />` to explicity indicates the places to scan the controllers and that's all.

Good luck!