# Spring, Serving static views from controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am getting `WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/fomoapp/resources/lib/login.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'fomo'` error. The following thread solutions are not working for me:

[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400282/org-springframework-web-servlet-pagenotfound-no-mapping-found-for-http-request)

What I see is that the application finds the right controller, then tries to find the `.html` file that I am returning from the method, but somehow fails to do this. Basically, I am trying to serve static resources from `resources/lib/` folder. The directory structure is the following:

[image]

`web.xml`:

[image]

`WEB-INF/applicationContext`:

[image]

`WEB-INF/spring/fomo-config.xml`:

[image]

and the controller looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Try removing all the `/resources` dir references. I don't know if you are using maven or not, but if you are... all files inside `src/main/resources` end up on your class-path so you never need to reference the "resources" dir itself, only sub-dirs.

Comment: just a quick comment: there's something I don't like in your configuration: you let the servlet to manage static contents through your <mvc:resources> tag, and, at the same time, your instruct your controller to manage the same path. You declare the resources path in your configuration file just not to have a controller configured for managing static resources! To me, you could just get rid of the whole controler if you need to serve a static html file.

Comment: I removed 'resources' references, but no success. I tried to access directly (without controller) from url the `.html` file, but can not.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mvc:resources` maps all requests to `resources/lib`. You should only map `/resources/**`, else your controllers will never be called.

Mvc resources "is" one controller specifically for `serving` static resources to the client (js/css/...), so you dont need your own.

Don't mix these resources with templates to be rendered by your controllers. Put them into another location, else they will be also available to the clients in their raw form.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I was trying to do is to start serving `.html` files as views, and it was not working due to the specified extension - `.html`. After changing it to `.jsp`, things start working good. So, I guess `InternalResourceViewResolver` needs `.jsp`s.

This was the main change needed (besides renaming the file to `.jsp`), in `fomo-config.xml`:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  

</bean>
```

As can be seen I have also separated static resources from views the way `Martin Frey` recommended. Maybe this was important too.

`applicationContext.xml` was changed to the following:

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Then, even though the `login` page loaded, static files inside of it were not, so I needed to do 2 things:

1. create another `resources` folder inside the `webapp` folder and move there all of my resources
2. Specify the mapping for files extensions inside of my `web.xml` the following way:

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

The directory structure looks like this now:

[image]

It is working fine now, but I am still not sure why at all we need `main/resources` folder if I can not access it other than by specifying the absolute path the way it is explained here:

http://akshaybobde.blogspot.com/2014/07/spring-mvc-serving-images-from-physical.html

I can not delete or move around it: the project just won't compile.

Comment: The `main/resources` folder will be accessible through the classpath, while the ones inside `webapp` will be on the servletpath. You can serve from both locations, but referencing them is slightly different. Spring doc explains this: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html